# Sending raw data using Network object in Unity3D

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, raw-data

I'm trying to create an iPad app that shows a controller and that controller sends data to a computer running the actual game. So I'm trying to send the value of the two joysticks on the iPad to the computer to control movement and camera without actually showing the joysticks on the computer. The same goes for the iPad; I only want to see the joysticks, not the actual gameplay. What is the best way of going about this? Maybe I'm just not fully aware of the functionally of the NetworkView object, but is there a simple way of only getting the transform data of the joystick without showing it? Or should I be doing something else entirely. Is there a way to just send raw data, like an array of ints, over via Network?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way of going about this?

You should check out some tutorials about networking and learn it's basics first.
[Packet Basics](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/63764-what-is-in-network-packets-tcpip-basics/)
[Networking Basics C Sharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using)

> Is there a way to just send raw data, like an array of ints, over via Network?

It is ofc possible to send raw data like int arrays, anyways you will just send them as bytes - but that is actually explained in the links I put up.

> Or should I be doing something else entirely?

It will take a lot of time to accomplish your goals, if you are new to networking and want to put yourself up with a project like yours, but nothing is impossible.

good luck though ;-)